# Ambiguity in master formula for cross section calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

During my studies of particle physics I encountered the master formula for calculating hadronic cross sections via factorization of the hadronic process into the sum of the partonic subprocesses, each convoluted with the parton distribution functions.

However, in different sources I find slightly different formulae.
In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2389v4) article on page 20 the cross section is differentiated with respect to the two momentum fractions:
$$
\sigma = \int_0^1 dx_1\int_0^1 dx_2\int d\Phi f_1(x_1,Q_1^2)f_2(x_2,Q_2^2)\frac{d\sigma}{dx_1dx_2d\Phi}
$$
In [this](https://indico.cern.ch/event/680421/contributions/3096162/attachments/1697092/2731944/J.Huston_Introduction_to_QCD_from_an_LHC_perspective-02.pdf) one on the other hand on page 14 it is just the differential cross section with respect to the phase-space volume:
$$
\sigma = \int_0^1 dx_1\int_0^1 dx_2\int d\Phi f_1(x_1,Q_1^2)f_2(x_2,Q_2^2)\frac{d\sigma}{d\Phi}
$$

What is the correct formula or are they the same? I thought maybe this $\mathrm dx_i$ in the denominator is just to "cancel" the other one in front of the integral. Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Hello! It would be great if you could add the two formulae to your post (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) typesetting). Thanks!

Comment: The first equation does not make much sense to me. For pdfs the momentum fractions $x_1$ and $x_2$ are parameters for the incoming momenta and hence are not part of the final state phase space. Further note that the $\sigma$ on the RHS is the parton-level (differential) cross section and is different from the $\sigma$ on the LHS, so it is a bit misleading to denote them by the same symbol.